# Intranet Site doesnt display in IE9 (Intermittent)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, windows-authentication

I have an ASP MVC 3 website which is used on the intranet. It uses Windows Authentication and I've noticed sometimes on just a few user's machines (they all use IE9), it just doesnt load and the user is presented with a white screen or "Internet Explorer cannot display this page" message.

I've set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` in my `<head>` tag and I've also unchecked the box "Display intranet sites in compatibility mode" under tools > Compatibility View Settings in IE9.

I'm running out of ideas as to what is causing this issue. It's intermittent too which is all the more puzzling. It works fine on everyone else's machine (some even use IE9 and the rest use IE8).

Comment: check eventviewer for some errors

Comment: I checked eventviewer, there are 0 errors under Internet Explorer

Comment: what about under your application?

Comment: I dont see my application in the eventviewer, should I be checking on the server machine or their local machines?

Comment: that should be on the server machine, if the result is a white page, try to view the html source that the client received, if it is different from you have expected then the problem is on the server side

Comment: if my assumption is correct that it is on the server-side, try viewing the iis logs if you couldn't find anything from the eventviewer

Comment: I've checked my eventviewer and theres nothing untoward in there, apart from an SceCli warning? But I dont think that is associated with my app, I'm unsure as it doesnt give much information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET MVC3, I'd strongly recommend installing [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It'll help you see what's happening on the server when the requests fail. Granted, you'd probably want to configure it to require authentication, but it can also be turned on and off in the web.config if you just need to it be available temporarily.

Comment: I solved it, seems it was some sort of DNS issue, if they used the fully qualified domain name, it worked